# How to use JSF component library with OSGI

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, osgi

I have a very specific questions about using JSF and component libraries.

I tested to build WAB (OSG-fied WAR) package with Primefaces. It turns out that there are problems in integrating JSF and Primefaces when using OSGI.

There are several ways to integrate JSF and Primefaces which I want to ask how to atchieve:

1. I can build Primefaces.jar as OSGI bundle. I can export the Java methods as services but there are xml configuration files and etc which I suppose I cannot use in separate OSGI bundle. Is this correct or am I wrong?
2. Is it possible to make a custom build of Mojarra with integrated Primefaces components. If I manage to do this I can simply deploy the modified Mojarra as Glassfish module build an use it very simple and efficient. If someone managed to achieve this would you share some information about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy `Primefaces.jar` as OSGI bundle in Glassfish. Copy the tags declaration from `primefaces-p.taglib.xml`. And also take a look at this [tutorial](http://simonmartinelli.blogspot.com/2009/09/create-custom-jsf-facelet-component.html) how to create custom tags.
I'm not sure but you also need to copy/paste the JS, css and pictures into you bundle.

Comment: could you elaborate? I tried deploying Primefaces jar as OSGi bundle in glassfish, and listed it as required plugin in in WAB, but it seems that the primefaces classes couldn't find any of the jsf classes that they need.

Comment: As far as I remember at the end I copied manually Primefaces.jar into lib folder located on Glassfish. I don't remember how I solved the issue exactly back in 2012.

Comment: I honestly tried putting the jar in EVERY lib dir I find reasonable inside the glassfish home dir, and repeat the cycle stop server - clear cache - restart countless of time and nothing worked. I'm so desperate...

Comment: Sorry, I can't propose any solution.